# Jquery form select option not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm new to Jquery and have a problem with the following:

I want to make a form select tree. If i select one option, another select shows up.
This code works fine in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome

**Jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#upgrade').click(function(){
           $('#showupgrade').show(1000);
           $('#showsysteem').hide();
           $('#shownetwerk').hide();
        });
        $('#system').click(function(){
           $('#showsysteem').show(1000);
           $('#showupgrade').hide();
           $('#shownetwerk').hide();
        });
        $('#choice').click(function(){
            $('#showsysteem').hide();
            $('#showupgrade').hide();
            $('#shownetwerk').hide();
        });
        $('#network').click(function(){
           $('#showsysteem').hide();
           $('#showupgrade').hide();
           $('#shownetwerk').show(1000);
        });
    });
    </script>

**HTML code:**

<td>
<select name="choice1[]">
<option id="choice" selected="selected">Maak uw keuze</option>
<option id="upgrade">PC upgrade</option>
<option id="system">Systeem</option>
<option id="network">Netwerk</option>
</select></td>
<td>
<select name="choice2[]" id="showupgrade" style="display: none;">
    <option>Upgrade Set</option>
    <option>Nieuwe voeding</option>
    <option>Intern geheugen</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="choice3[]" id="showsysteem" style="display: none;">
    <option>APK</option>
    <option>Virus verwijderen</option> 
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="choice4[]" id="shownetwerk" style="display: none;">
    <option>Wi-Fi</option>
    <option>Netwerk installatie</option>    
</select>

</td>
```

Comment: The option tag cannot have an id-attibute. You need to use the value attribute instead and handle the onChange event of the first select to get the current selected value.

Answer (score 6):

You should probably be binding to the change event and then pulling out the value selected rather than binding to a specific option.

```
$("#idofparent").change(function() {
     var selected = $(this).val();
     if (selected === "upgrade") {
         $('#showupgrade').show(1000);
         $('#showsysteem').hide();
         $('#shownetwerk').hide();
     }

     //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the events for only one event for the select

```
$('#choice1').change(function(){
         if($('#choice1').val()=='upgrade'){
           $('#showupgrade').show(1000);
           $('#showsysteem').hide();
           $('#shownetwerk').hide();
        }
        else if ($('#choice1').val()=='system'){
         ....
}
....
```

});

And make differents event using $('#choice1').val() (Return selected value from the select)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wnnV/

The javascript can be shortened to:

```
// #mainselect is the id for the first select you used
$('#mainselect').change(function() {

    var id = $(this).val();

    if (id === '') {
        $('select').not('#mainselect').hide();
    } else {
        $('#' + id).show(1000);

        $('select').not('#mainselect, #' + id).hide();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I simpler and clean coded way of achieving this would be to add a value="" to each  item in the main  that matches the ID of the corresponding  tag you wish to show.  You can view the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/HYkk3/1/

```
    <script>
    $('#mainselect').change(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      if (id === 'makeChoice') {
         $('select').not('#mainselect').hide();
      } else {
         $('#' + id).show();
         $('select').not('#mainselect, #' + id).hide();
      }
    });​
    </script>
    <body>
      <td>
      <select id="mainselect" name="choice1">
         <option value="makeChoice" selected="selected">Make a Choice</option>
         <option value="pcUpgrade">PC upgrade</option>
         <option value="system">System</option>
         <option value="network">Network</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <select name="pcUpgrade" id="pcUpgrade" style="display: none;">
         <option>Upgrade Set</option>
         <option>Nieuwe voeding</option>
         <option>Intern geheugen</option>
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <select name="choice3" id="system" style="display: none;">
         <option>APK</option>
         <option>Virus verwijderen</option> 
      </select>
      </td>
      <td>
      <select name="choice4" id="network" style="display: none;">
         <option>Wi-Fi</option>
         <option>Netwerk installatie</option>    
      </select>
      </td>
      </body>
```